# Does the MVS algorithm in this case give a bad build list, that is, a build list with a redundant module?

Tags: go

I am reading the [MVS algorithm used](https://research.swtch.com/vgo-mvs) for selecting build list in golang and I have one question for algorithm 1 from the paper.

I am using the example from the paper.

A **rough build list** is just made by following the arrows, so, in this case, it's `[A.1, B 1.2, D 1.3, E 1.2, C 1.2, D 1.4]` and then omitting the lower version modules we can get **the build list**. So the build list is: `[A.1, B 1.2, E 1.2, C 1.2, D 1.4]` (we omitted `D 1.3` in favor of `D 1.4`). However, what would the build list be if `D 1.4` was not connected to (not referencing) `E 1.2`. Algorithmically it would also be `[A.1, B 1.2, E 1.2, C 1.2, D 1.4]`, since the rough build list is the same, so is the build list. However, looking logically, `E 1.2` is redundant here since nothing points (references) it.

Does anyone know what the build list would look like if `D 1.4` was not connected to (not referencing) `E 1.2`? Would it really be the same as it is connected? Is `E 1.2` redundant in this case?

[image]